# MVC5 Identity How to add new attributes and extend ApplicationUser class

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity

This is a MVC5 with Identity Web application. I'm trying to add a drop down list in my register view so when a person registers themselves they can select their role. My Register View model currently only has a drop down list for Department and Depot which were successful but when I try to replicate it for roles it doesn't work.

Note: I'm envisioning that all my Roles will be in my dbo.AspNetRoles table and all the users that have been assigned to these roles will be in my dbo.AspNetUserRoles table.

I know i need to do the following things for this to work but I'm not sure if I'm missing out anything:

1. Create a class with an ID and a name (In my IdentityModels.cs )
2. Create a ViewModel (RegisterViewMode)

Add a  (RoleList) to display the objects in the drop down list

3. Modify the model

(ConfigureRegisterViewModel method)  in the accounts controller POST Method to accommodate the role id

4. Code the CSHTML in the Views (Which I've done)

This is the error that I'm get in my AccountController on this line

`IEnumerable<RegisterViewModel> roles = db.Roles.OrderBy(u => u.Name);`

> Cannot implicitly convert type
>   'System.Linq.IOrderedQueryable'
>   to
>   'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable'.
>   An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Can someone who is an expert with MVC point me to the right direction as to how to do this? In the future I will be modify my ApplicationUser class and this RegisterViewModel to add more variables in e.g: Age, Street Address and Job Position etc

This is a snippet of my RegisterViewModel

```
public class RegisterViewModel
{
        //RoleID
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
        //RoleName
        [Display(Name = "RoleName")]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> RolesList { get; set; }

        //Department and Depot
        public int DepotID { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> DepotList { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> DepartmentList { get; set; }
        public int DepartmentID { get; set; }

}
```

This is my POST and GET method for Register 
AccountController.cs

```
    // GET: /Account/Register
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult Register()
    {
        RegisterViewModel model = new RegisterViewModel();
        ConfigureRegisterViewModel(model);
        return View(model);
    }

    //
    // POST: /Account/Register
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Register(RegisterViewModel model)
    {

        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            ConfigureRegisterViewModel(model);
            return View(model);
        }
            var user = new ApplicationUser() {
                UserName = model.Email,
                Email = model.Email,
                FirstMidName = model.FirstMidName,
                LastName = model.LastName,
                EnrollmentDate = model.EnrollmentDate,
                DepotID = model.DepotID,
                DepartmentID = model.DepartmentID,
                Id = model.Id //My RoleID
            };
            var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                var code = await UserManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user.Id);
                var callbackUrl = Url.Action("ConfirmEmail", "Account", new { userId = user.Id, code = code }, protocol: Request.Url.Scheme);
                await UserManager.SendEmailAsync(user.Id, "Confirm your account", "Please confirm your account by clicking this link: <a href=\"" + callbackUrl + "\">link</a>");
                ViewBag.Link = callbackUrl;

            return View("DisplayEmail");
            }
        AddErrors(result);
        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        ConfigureRegisterViewModel(model);
        return View(model);
    }

    private void ConfigureRegisterViewModel(RegisterViewModel model)
    {
        IEnumerable<Department> departments = db.Departments.OrderBy(u => u.DepartmentName);
        model.DepartmentList = departments.Select(a => new SelectListItem
        {
            Value = a.DepartmentID.ToString(),
            Text = a.DepartmentName.ToString()
        });
        IEnumerable<Depot> depots = db.Depots.OrderBy(u => u.DepotName);
        model.DepotList = depots.Select(a => new SelectListItem
        {
            Value = a.DepotID.ToString(),
            Text = a.DepotName.ToString()
        });
        IEnumerable<RegisterViewModel> roles = db.Roles.OrderBy(u => u.Name); <-- ERROR HERE 
        model.RolesList = roles.Select(a => new SelectListItem
        {
            Value = a.Id.ToString(),
            Text = a.Name.ToString()
        });

    }
```

Register.cshtml

```
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Id, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Id, Model.RolesList, "Please select", new { @class = "form-control" })
                </div>
            </div>
```

**THIS CODE IS FOR REFERENCE ONLY**

IdentityModel.cs (ApplicationUser class)

```
namespace RecreationalServicesTicketingSystem.Models
{
    public class ApplicationUserLogin : IdentityUserLogin<int> { }
    public class ApplicationUserClaim : IdentityUserClaim<int> { }
    public class ApplicationUserRole : IdentityUserRole<int> { }

    public class ApplicationRole : IdentityRole<int, ApplicationUserRole>, IRole<int>
    {
        public string Description { get; set; }

        public ApplicationRole() : base() { }
        public ApplicationRole(string name)
            : this()
        {
            this.Name = name;
        }

        public ApplicationRole(string name, string description)
            : this(name)
        {
            this.Description = description;
        }
    }

    public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser<int, ApplicationUserLogin, ApplicationUserRole, ApplicationUserClaim>, IUser<int>
    {
        public async Task<ClaimsIdentity>
            GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser, int> manager)
        {
            var userIdentity = await manager
                .CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
            return userIdentity;
        }

        public bool IsAdministrator { get; set; }
        [StringLength(50, MinimumLength = 1)]

        public string LastName { get; set; }
        [StringLength(50, MinimumLength = 1, ErrorMessage = "First name cannot be longer than 50 characters.")]

        [Column("FirstName")]
        public string FirstMidName { get; set; }

        public string FullName
        {
            get { return FirstMidName + " " + LastName; }
        }
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        public DateTime EnrollmentDate { get; set; }
        public int DepartmentID { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("DepartmentID")]
        public virtual Department Department { get; set; }
        public int DepotID { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("DepotID")]
        public virtual Depot Depot { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Ticket> Tickets { get; set; }


        //Adding Roles to Register page code start
        //RoleID
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
        //RoleName
        [Display(Name = "RoleName")]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        //Adding Roles to Register page code end

    }


    public class ApplicationDbContext
        : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole, int,
        ApplicationUserLogin, ApplicationUserRole, ApplicationUserClaim>
    {

        public ApplicationDbContext()
            : base("DefaultConnection")
        {
        }

        static ApplicationDbContext()
        {
            Database.SetInitializer<ApplicationDbContext>(new ApplicationDbInitializer());
        }


        public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
        {
            return new ApplicationDbContext();
        }


        public DbSet<Ticket> Tickets { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Category> Categories { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Department> Departments { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Depot> Depots { get; set; }


    }



    public class ApplicationUserStore :
    UserStore<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole, int,
    ApplicationUserLogin, ApplicationUserRole, ApplicationUserClaim>, IUserStore<ApplicationUser, int>, IDisposable
    {
        public ApplicationUserStore()
            : this(new IdentityDbContext())
        {
            base.DisposeContext = true;
        }

        public ApplicationUserStore(DbContext context)
            : base(context)
        {
        }
    }


    public class ApplicationRoleStore
    : RoleStore<ApplicationRole, int, ApplicationUserRole>,
    IQueryableRoleStore<ApplicationRole, int>,
    IRoleStore<ApplicationRole, int>, IDisposable
    {
        public ApplicationRoleStore()
            : base(new IdentityDbContext())
        {
            base.DisposeContext = true;
        }

        public ApplicationRoleStore(DbContext context)
            : base(context)
        {
        }




    }



}
```

Comment: the way you added new properties to your `ApplicationUser`-class is correct (to answere your question in the heading) but man, you got a real mess in your code (comments, attributes, empty line-breaks,...) you really should clean this up..

Comment: @MatthiasBurger Yeah this is kind of like a draft for me. What about the steps I took adding new properties and drop down list. Are those correct?

Comment: yeah dropdownlist is such a thing. the best here is to really work with the debugger, since I'm working with them since beginning of ASP 5 and I still do mistakes. But if the type is correct I don't see any problems for now.

Comment: @MatthiasBurger I have such difficulty solving problems with a debugger. I know it's one of the most important tool for a programmer but it's so hard to learn.

Comment: I'd go a step further and say it **is** the most important tool. I learned programming without debugger. But now I'd miss it. Maybe start learning how the debugger works on an easy console-application. Set some breakpoints, start it and see what it does. :)

Answer (score 1):

You are missing `ToList()` function. `ToList` will help you convert it into `IEnumerable`. It should be

```
IEnumerable<RegisterViewModel> roles = db.Roles.OrderBy(u => u.Name).ToList();
```

Comment: But why does it work for Department and Depot?       `IEnumerable<Depot> depots = db.Depots.OrderBy(u => u.DepotName);` and  `IEnumerable<Depot> depots = db.Depots.OrderBy(u => u.DepotName);`

Comment: I also tried your way but it came out with this error `Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<RecreationalServicesTicketingSystem.Models.ApplicationRole>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<RecreationalServicesTicketingSystem.Models.RegisterViewModel> An explicit conversion exists ( are you missing a cast?)'
`

Comment: @TykiMikk is class `RegisterViewModel` the same with class `roles` in DB?

Comment: I found the answer it's suppose to be `IEnumerable<ApplicationRole> roles = db.Roles.OrderBy(u => u.Name).ToList();`

Answer (score 0):

The solution is

IEnumerable< ApplicationRole> roles = db.Roles.OrderBy(u => u.Name).ToList();